# Add color for header columns file csv by pandas(or any library) with python

Tags: python, pandas, styles

I'm trying write data to file csv, that done, but I want to add style(color, both...) for header/row data in csv file.

I'm trying research, but I only found suggest for excel file.

Can you please help me this case ?

Thanks all!

Comment: if want `csv` there is not possible add colors, but to excel file yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is a pure data format without any formatting. It's a plain text file after all. So no, there is no way of adding colour. Go for Excel if you want this functionality.